# Parsing a generated method declaration in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

With TypeScript, in Visual Studio Code, I start out with the following line in my React app's render method:

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={this.load}>Load</button>
```

I use Visual Studio Code's built-in helper to generate the method `load` for me, and it generates:

```
load(): ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
}
```

I can't find documentation for this declaration style and can't quite parse it mentally.

- What is the `| undefined { throw ... }` doing?
- What does the `=> void` mean? I assumed it meant the method returns `void`, but if I don't return something in the method body, I get an error.

Is this declaration style known as a specific declaration style I could research further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets remove the TS

```
load() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
}
```

That's just the normal JS part. Now sprinkling back in the types:

```
load(): (event) => void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
}
```

`this.load` is a function with event argument that returns void. Let's extract that out:

```
type LoadFunction = (event) => void
load(): LoadFunction | undefined {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
}
```

`this.load` is either `LoadFunction` OR it's `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`load()` method has to return event handler function or undefined.

If it returns function, signutare has to be:

```js
(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void
```

else

```js
undefined
```

Reason why event handler function is wrapped in extra parenthesis is to separate it from `undefined` result. Without extra parentheses, result type of `load()` would be event handler that returns:

```js
...=> void | undefined
```

Curly braces are then just implementation of `load()` method:

```js
load() {
    // not implemented yet. Implementation will replace throwing of an exception.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question.

You can read "Method not implemented"

It means the load function is not defined, you need to check if it's already written somewhere in your code or to write it.